# How to ignore HTML component with specific CSS class

Tags: jquery

i have many links in page but few links has few specific css class attached. i want to avoid those link which has .noclass attached. the below code solve my problem.

```
<a href="#" class="noclass">Link with No class1</a><br/>
<a href="#" class="noclass">Link with No class2</a><br/>
<a href="#" >Link without No class</a><br/><br/>

<div id="footer_column6">
  <a href="#" class="noclass">Link with No class</a><br/>
  <a href="#" class="">Link without No class</a><br/>
  <a href="#" class="">Link without No class</a>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hyperLink = $("a:not(.noclass)");
    $.each(hyperLink, function(index, value) {
      var href = $(value).attr("href");
      //Test code to update the back ground
      $(value).css("background-color", "red");
      $(value).attr("href", "/" + countrycode + (href == '/' ? '' : href));
      href = $(value).attr("href");
    });
});
```

when the scenario is bit different like i want to ignore anything with css class .noclass then above code is not working.

suppose if few links are there in div where noclass has been attached to div and i do not want to iterate links in those div which has no class attached.

so if noclass is attached directly with links or may be noclass may attached to parent like div or span. in this case i do not want to iterate links if its parent has no class attached. so tell me what little modification i have to add in above jquery code.

thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what the question/problem is,tbh

Comment: Looks like there's some code missing. What is `countrycode`?

Comment: Assuming you've defined `countrycode` properly, the code appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4zm42316/

Comment: He says that the below code solve his problem... I'm confused too....

Comment: I guess that you don't want to select links INSIDE div container? You want to skip last two links?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan probably user:delinear gave here right code. i have not test it.....will ley you know. i want to ignore links with noclass and also want to ignore if parent has noclass attached but inside parent links has no noclass attached. so in that case i want to ignore parent. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have revised my previous code, I realised there was a logic flaw and also didn't like that it relied on adding an extra outer div to make it work. This version selects all links initially and then from within your .each, it tests if the link as the .noclass or has an ancestor with .noclass:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hyperLink = $("a");
    $.each(hyperLink, function(index, value) {
        if($(this).hasClass('noclass') || $(this).parents('.noclass').length) {
        return;
      }
      var href = $(value).attr("href");
      //Test code to update the back ground
      $(value).css("background-color", "red");
      $(value).attr("href", "/" + countrycode + (href == '/' ? '' : href));
      href = $(value).attr("href");
    });
});
```

This is more robust as it also works with links at the root of the page, and for any kind of wrapper element (div, span, section, article, etc).

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nrd4rru2/) example (note, I had to comment out the countrycode line to make the Fiddle work, as countrycode is not defined).

Comment: if possible please add one jsfiddle link with your code. i will test and let you know.thanks.

Comment: I think that OP actually wants to skip links inside div container, under some conditions...

Comment: @sinisake that's what the code does, it selects ONLY links that do not have .noclass that are inside divs or spans that ALSO do not have .noclass. Unless I'm mistaken, basically he is asking for a method to select all links, but to be able to exclude links by adding .noclass either to the link itself or to the wrapper.

Comment: sorry i test the above but it is not working here is jsfiddle version https://jsfiddle.net/6zw9grs2/1/

Comment: @Thomas, sorry I realised there was a flaw in my original logic, try the revised version with Fiddle.